# Dropzone not showing when using jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have a function that receives data from a server and shows a dropzone.js form,

```
function requestData() {
    // showDropzone();   // displaying dropzone from here works,
    $.post("/userids/",null, function(data, status) {
        jsonarray = JSON.parse(data);
        showDropzone(); // here, it calls the function but dropzone is not displayed
    });
}

function showDropzone(){
    $("#content").html('<form id="dropzone" action="/target" class="dropzone"></form>');
}
```

Dropzone doesn't show when I call it from inside the post method, but it does when I call it from outside of it. I have no idea what is causing this, there is no error or warning, and I've tried with all possible dropzone configurations, but even forceFallback set to true doesn't work.

EDIT: 
Here is the complete html,

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dropzone.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            requestData();
        });

        function requestData() {
            // showDropzone();   // displaying dropzone from here works,
            $.post("/userids/",null, function(data, status) {
                jsonarray = JSON.parse(data);
                showDropzone(); // here, it calls the function but dropzone is not displayed
            });
        }

        function showDropzone(){
            $("#content").html('<form id="dropzone" action="/target" class="dropzone"></form>');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you console.log(); 'ed it? 
Insert one into showDropzone(); and one into post response.
PS: Show html code (jsfiddle is welcome) :)

Comment: everything is getting called as it's supposed to, only the dropzone form is not showing when called from inside $.post.

Answer (score 0):

:D I bet form#dropzone adds to the #content, but you don't see it ... because it's EMPTY!! (no input inside) :D  Check out my fiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/U5wCw/

Change your code to

```
$("#content").html('<form id="dropzone" action="/target" class="dropzone"><input type="text"/></form>');
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer? :)

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm guessing the problem is a little more complex than that.

Comment: JSON.parse requires string as an argument - i bet you're aware of that but i must ask! :) Is  data (at line  
    jsonarray = JSON.parse(data);)
a string? :)
Second guess change name of the function showDropzone to showDropzoneXXX and then check.    I've made another fiddle but i didn't include dropzone.js (http://jsfiddle.net/sE7um/10/). Tell me where can I download it from?

Comment: If I take out the showDropbox() function the code works perfectly and when I put the function before the $.post handler the code works perfectly. It's only when I use it inside $.post that dropzone.js doesn't show anything, and even then, the rest of the code works.

Dropzone is available at http://www.dropzonejs.com

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sE7um/12/
Now it's completely your code!! I've even included dropzone.js. Please , in your code, comment line with JSON.parse and paste here EXACT output of variable data.